# Python Programmer test

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to test python programmers as part of my hiring process.

I can understand python and follow the flow but have no idea how to technically challenge someone.

Can someone recommend an online test?

Thanks

Comment: Uhm, no offense, but if your abilities about Python are limited to what you said, you should leave the job of evaluating your candidates' technical abilities to someone who knows a bit more (although an online test can be useful to screen out the worst candidates).

Comment: I do have someone to round off final technical interview but wanted to have a first phase filter in place like you said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's been plenty of such discussions over at /r/Python. Here's one:

http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1knw7z/python_interview_questions/

Answer (score 0):

What do specifically want to check?

- Their algorithm skills?
- Knowledge of specific python technologies (such as django)?
- Python pit falls compered to other 3 generation language?
- For the first one any interview question can be ok (like how to reverse a linked list, or sort an sorted binary tree and so on) you can find more here http://programmerinterview.com/index.php/data-structures/introduction
- For the second ones it more depends on what are you looking for (web developer, server side and so on).